# Help with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Based on the following table

```
ID      Effort      Name
-------------------------
1       1           A
2       1           A
3       8           A
4       10          B
5       4           B
6       1           B
7       10          C
8       3           C
9       30          C
```

I want to check if the total effort against a name is less than 40 then add a row with effort = 40 - (Total Effort) for the name. The ID of the new row can be anything. If the total effort is greater than 40 then trucate the data for one of the rows to make it 40.

So after applying the logic above table will be

```
ID      Effort      Name
-------------------------
1       1           A
2       1           A
3       8           A
10      30          A

4       10          B
5       4           B
6       1           B
11      25          B

7       10          C
8       3           C
9       27          C
```

I was thinking of opening a cursor, keeping a counter of the total effort, and based on the logic insert existing and new rows in another temporary table.

I am not sure if this is an efficient way to deal with this. I would like to learn if there is a better way.

Comment: the truncate one seems under specified -  which row should be selected to be reduced? can a row be deleted to meet the condition? can multiple rows? (ie, say you had 42 entries each of which had an effort of 1)

Comment: What do you wish to do if none of the rows can be truncated by the value you are over with? if you have 45 rows all with 1? Now this will not just be an **UPDATE/INSERT** query, but also a DELETE?

Comment: yes rows can be deleted as well. so if the total effort is 42 hours with 42 entries. the last 2 entries can be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2008`, this may be done with a single `MERGE` statement:

```
DECLARE @efforts TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, effort INT NOT NULL, name CHAR(1))

INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (1, 1, 'A'),
        (2, 1, 'A'),
        (3, 8, 'A'),
        (4, 10, 'B'),
        (5, 4, 'B'),
        (6, 1, 'B'),
        (7, 10, 'C'),
        (8, 3, 'C'),
        (9, 30, 'C'),
        (10, 60, 'C')

SELECT  *
FROM    @efforts
ORDER BY
        name, id

;WITH    total AS
        (       SELECT  *
                FROM    @efforts e
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) +
                        (
                        SELECT  MAX(id)
                        FROM    @efforts
                        ),
                        40 - SUM(effort),
                        name
                FROM    @efforts
                GROUP BY
                        name
                HAVING  SUM(effort) < 40
        ),
        source AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                (
                SELECT  SUM(effort)
                FROM    total ep
                WHERE   ep.name = e.name
                        AND ep.id <= e.id
                ) AS ce,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  SUM(effort)
                FROM    total ep
                WHERE   ep.name = e.name
                        AND ep.id < e.id
                ), 0) AS cp
        FROM    total e
        )
MERGE
INTO    @efforts e
USING   source s
ON      e.id = s.id
WHEN MATCHED AND 40 BETWEEN cp AND ce THEN
UPDATE
SET     e.effort = s.effort + 40 - ce
WHEN MATCHED AND cp > 40 THEN
DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT  (id, effort, name)
VALUES  (id, effort, name);

SELECT  *
FROM    @efforts
ORDER BY
        name, id
```

In `SQL Server 2005`, you'll need two statements (in one transaction):

```
DECLARE @efforts TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, effort INT NOT NULL, name CHAR(1))

INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (1, 1, 'A')

INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (2, 1, 'A')
INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (3, 8, 'A')
INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (4, 10, 'B')
INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (5, 4, 'B')
INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (6, 1, 'B')
INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (7, 10, 'C')
INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (8, 3, 'C')
INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (9, 30, 'C')
INSERT
INTO    @efforts
VALUES  (10, 60, 'C')

;WITH    total AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  SUM(effort)
                FROM    @efforts ep
                WHERE   ep.name = e.name
                        AND ep.id <= e.id
                ), 0) AS cp
        FROM    @efforts e
        )
DELETE
FROM    total
WHERE   cp > 40

INSERT
INTO    @efforts
SELECT  (
        SELECT  MAX(id)
        FROM    @efforts
        ) +
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name),
        40 - SUM(effort),
        name
FROM    @efforts
GROUP BY
        name
HAVING  SUM(effort) < 40

SELECT  *
FROM    @efforts
ORDER BY
        name, id
```

Comment: My bad. I am connected to a 2005 database. it is giving me incorrect syntax near 'MERGE' error. Is there a work around for 2005 to use MERGE ? Thanks

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: not with a single statement.

Answer (score 4):

I think the first part could be done this way:

```
 INSERT INTO tbl(Effort, Name)
 SELECT 40 - SUM(Effort), Name
 FROM tbl
 GROUP BY Name
 HAVING SUM(Effort) < 40)
```

The second part is harder. Perhaps you could do something like this instead?

```
 INSERT INTO tbl(Effort, Name)
 SELECT 40 - SUM(Effort), Name
 FROM tbl
 GROUP BY Name
 HAVING SUM(Effort) <> 40)
```

What this does is, rather than making changes to your actual data, adds a row with a *negative* number for the Name if the total effort is > 40 hours, or a *positive* value if it is < 40 hours. This seems much safer for your data integrity than messing with the original values.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am getting the results but now the question  is how do i delete the rows that are beyond 40 hours. i.e applying the 2nd query you mentioned gives me
A 20
A 10
A 20
A 20
A -30

I would like the result to be 
A 20
A 10
A 10  [deleted one row and truncated the last by 10]

So now the total is 40.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the names that need modify:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Effort)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(Effort) < 40
```

Select this into a temp table, Add a column for 40 - SUM, then create an insert statement from that.  Much better than a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

```
This will do the first part:

Insert Into dbo.Test (Name, Effort)
Select t.Name, 40 - SUM(t.Effort)
From dbo.Test t
Group By t.Name
Having SUM(t.Effort) < 40
```

And this will do the second part:

```
Update a
Set a.Effort = a.Effort - b.AmountToDeduct
From dbo.Test a
Join (
         Select t.Name, (40 - SUM(t.Effort)) as 'AmountToDeduct'
         From dbo.Test t
         Group By t.Name
         Having SUM(t.Effort) > 40
     )b on a.Name = b.Name
Where a.ID = (Select MAX(c.ID) 
              From dbo.Test c   
          Where c.Name = a.Name
        )
```